# Custom Filters in Futter?

Tags: flutter, image, filter, editing

I want to apply **custom filters in a photo editing flutter app** , i don't know either it should be done using **flutter or from backend and if flutter then how** ?

I tried adding an overlay of the filter on a image which failed badly so i need to edit the saved image in order to achieve this I also tried matrix but it is still not giving me complete result.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor_pro

Comment: or try to use https://pub.dev/packages/photofilters